# Extracting images from URL with multiple extensions

Tags: java, image, url

I am trying to extract an image from the requested website, then save it to a folder.  The only problem is that the website I am pulling the image from has multiple image formats.  So the extension for the image would be either png, jpg, or gif.  I need to save all of these, but I do not know how to tell my program to extract multiple formats rather than just one..

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main { 
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int avatarnum = 1;
        String extension = null;
        BufferedImage image = null;
        extension = "jpg";

        while(avatarnum <= 1000){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://forum.blockland.us/avatarUpload/avatar_"+avatarnum+"."+extension);
                image = ImageIO.read(url);

                try{
                    ImageIO.write(image, extension,new File("C:\\test\\"+avatarnum+"."+extension));
                    System.out.println("Write successful");
                    avatarnum ++;
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Printing stacktrace");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                avatarnum ++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found! " + avatarnum);
                System.out.println("Adding one to variable and retrying..");
                avatarnum ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

As of now, only jpg images are being extracted from the website and saved to the folder.
For testing purposes it will only pull 1,000 images from the site.

I will be using this to make an "avatar database" if anyone was wondering.

Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need iterate over multiple image formats (extensions):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int avatarnum = 1;
    BufferedImage image = null;

    String[] extensions = { "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp" };

    while (avatarnum <= 1000) {
        for (String extension : extensions) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://forum.blockland.us/avatarUpload/avatar_" + avatarnum + "." + extension);
                image = ImageIO.read(url);

                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, extension, new File("C:\\test\\" + avatarnum + "." + extension));
                    System.out.println("Write successful");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error on save the image");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found! " + avatarnum + "." + extension);

            }
        }
        avatarnum++;
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an array with all valid extensions

```
String[] extensions = {"jpg", "png", "gif" };
```

And loop over all of them when retreive the URL

```
try {
    for (String extension: extensions){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://forum.blockland.us/avatarUpload/avatar_"+avatarnum+"."+extension);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (Exception e){
             //Wrong extension (or other kind of error)
        }
    }
    ...
```

For every image, it will fail with the wrong extensions, but will retreive the one with the correct